# Shell script to verify the directory name and set environmental variables

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Script to verify/validate the directory name and set environmental variables based on $d in the for loop.
but if validation is not working.
Request for help

```
for d in */; do
# Will print */ if no directories are available
echo $d
#tempdir='mkdir /home/Dinesh_Sadu/Scripting/Run-$d'
pwd=dinesh_S
`cd /home/Dinesh_Sadu/Scripting`
tempfile=`mkdir -p Run_$pwd`
`cp mkdir_p.sh $tempfile.txt`
var="$d"
echo "*****"$var
if [ $var = "a" ]; then
    echo "Dinesh Sadu in A"
    export sandbox="/home/Dinesh/aaaa
fi
if [ $var = "b" ]; then
    echo "Dinesh Sadu B"
    export sandbox="/home/Dinesh/bbb
fi   
echo "######:$sandbox"
done
```

**Script to verify/validate the directory name and set environmental variables**

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. I am sorry to say that, but your program has so many issues, and this is neither a code writing, nor a code testing service. It would be a good idea to read about shell scripting a bit more before you start writing programs. If you search the web, you'll find lots of tutorials on that. And then, use shellcheck.net, it will tell you all your syntax and some other errors.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelJaros

Can you tell me how to validate directory names in shell script